# Scraper getting only a few names out of numerous

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a scraper in python in combination with selenium to get all the product names from redmart.com. Every time I run my code, i get only 27 names from that page although the page has got numerous names. FYI, the page has got lazy-loading method enabled. My scraper can reach the bottom of the page but scrape only 27 names. I can't understand where I'm getting lost with the logic I've applied in my scraper. Hope to get any workaround.

Here is the script I've written so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver; import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

driver.get("https://redmart.com/new")
check_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight;")

while True:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    try:
        wait.until(lambda driver: driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight;")  > check_height)
        check_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight;") 
    except:
         break

for names in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.description'):
    item_name = names.find_element_by_css_selector('h4 a').text
    print(item_name)

driver.quit()
```

Comment: This site is quite curious.  Assuming that you have permission to scrape the site (per their Terms of Use), you might ask them for help.  Just watching the HTML of the page change as I scroll up and down the page, it appears that they are dynamically loading and unloading content from the page.  This would explain why your code is only seeing a small subset of items that you were expecting.  Perhaps they can provide you with a more convenient API to access the information that you require.

Comment: @ Breaks Software, I'm not at all interested in their data. What I would like to learn is how to deal with the situation I'm facing while scraping a site like this.

Comment: Since they seem to be dynamically loading and unloading the content, I'm not sure that there is an effective way to use Selenium, or any other browser scraping tool, to approach this problem.  Have you tried to include the "for" block of code inside of your "while" block, storing the captured items in a list/dictionary/whatever as you go?

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait for new content to be loaded.

Here is a very simple example:

```
    driver.get('https://redmart.com/new')
    products = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="description"]/h4/a')
    print(len(products))  # 18 products
    driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);')
    time.sleep(5)  # wait for new content to be loaded
    products = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="description"]/h4/a')
    print(len(products))  # 36 products
```

It works.

You can also look at XHR requests and try to scrape anything You want without using "time.sleep()" and "driver.execute_script".

For example, while scrolling their website, new products are loaded from this URL:
`https://api.redmart.com/v1.6.0/catalog/search?q=new&pageSize=18&page=1`

As you can see, it is possible to modify parameters like **pageSize** (max 100 products) and **page**. With this URL you can scrape all products without even using Selenium and Chrome. You can do all of this with [Python Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)

Comment: Thanks mostaszewski, for your answer. You have shown in your example that I should let my scraper wait a little while to get the newly loaded content and for that you have set a hardcoded delay which is 5 seconds in this case. I did the same with explicit wait and I did it at the same position where you have shown in the above example to place the argument for delay. Where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Calm down please, i thought you changed something in your code.
The problem is that you wait for script to be executed. It doesn't make sense. You have to wait for website to be loaded.

Comment: What is this line `wait.until(lambda driver: driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight;")  > check_height)` doing in the script then? Doesn't it wait for the content to be loaded?

Comment: No, it doesn't. It just waits for change of height value.

Comment: This is where I'm getting lost. I thought the newly loaded contents are also coming along with height value. Thanks a lot to make me understand. However, do you have any idea how can i get the page content as well with the explicit wait?

Comment: You're welcome. You can try to find an element on this website which is always loaded when you scroll down and then you can use [expected conditions](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html). But as i said above, in your case much faster and easier way is to use requests library and send requests to `https://api.redmart.com/v1.6.0/catalog/search?q=new&pageSize=18&page=1`. Response will be in JSON format so it is an additional argument to do it in this way.

Comment: Thanks for the clue. I'm trying to solve that now. If i can do it myself I'm gonna accept your answer. Btw, i'm not interested in their data, so usage of `api` is irrelevant. I just want to solve the way I started.

Comment: No problem. If you need any help feel free to ask me. Good luck.

Comment: @Shahin You can wait until "loading spinner" will disappear. Here is an example, i tested it and it works.
`wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "spinner")))`